# do you know how to remove vscode error underline in php when i define constant?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, constants, formatter, underline

in my vscode I define constant and when i want to print it,  vscode gives error and red underline. but it works (prints). I want to remove this error underline but how, i don't know. can you help?

```
$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "password";
$db['db_name'] = "cms";

foreach ($db as $key => $value) {
    define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

IT works. but VSCODE marks red underline at bottom DB_HOST,DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME.

I FIX this problem just change code like :

```
 $connection = mysqli_connect(constant("DB_HOST"), constant("DB_USER"), constant("DB_PASS"), constant("DB_NAME"));
```

Comment: Please add the code that shows the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I EDIT my question.

Comment: there are at least a few ways to share something to entire application and not adding 'it' to global constants: [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), [singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/php/example), static class, not static class... and ok, you stick with array - from php7 you can define array as constant

Answer (score 1):

VS Code doesn't actually execute your code, so it doesn't know the constants you have just defined in your code. It cannot pick up the `define`s executed within the loop.

If you replace your loop with

```php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'cms');
```

It should be smart enough to detect the `define` commands and the names that have been passed to it, and not give you any error.

Alternatively, do you need to `define` these variables? You could just use the `$db` variable to populate your connection:

```php
$connection = mysqli_connect($db['db_host'], $db['db_user'], $db['db_pass'], $db['db_name']);
```

Comment: thanks)  i'm a beginner. teacher in udemy course  `defined`  like that. for secure. his text editor different.

Comment: @BakuLik, out of curiosity, can you share some "secure" context of defining constants from array?